# Ubuntu shuts off my bluetooth device when reconnecting

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and have paired my bluetooth headset with it(Senheiser HD1 in-ears if that is relevant).  However, when I attempt to reconnect after disconnecting for whatever reason, if the headset is already connected to another device(my phone usually) instead of reconnecting it will actually power off my headset.  Sometimes I will hear the beginning of the "connected" message that the headset plays when it connects to a device before it abruptly cuts off as it powers down.

This is completely baffling me as I didn't even realize the computer could command the headset to shutdown remotely.